# Building a simple dialog with 2 choices on button click

Tags: 7, javascript

i am quite new with JS, Jquery UI experimentation.
I know the basics of Drupal 7 and i am working with some cool new functionalities on my personal website.
The latest one i would like to introduce is the possibility to click on my "CV" icon and show the user a super-simple jquery dialog with two buttons to either choose the IT or EN version.
To better understand what is that i want to implement, you can check a really simple graphic result at the link below.

[example image](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/9706192/header.PNG)

So what are my actual options? Should i code a custom block for this? or is there a chance i can build all this by inserting code inside the block body?
Can you point me a tutorial that shows some easy examples on how to implement basic structure like my case?

Thank you :)

Comment: I would add this question to the js section of stack exchange as it is not really a Drupal question.. :)

Comment: You're right but i guess that is better to point at Drupal experts rather than Js ones as the main request is pretty simple. What i don't know is how to implement what i want to do inside a Drupal block basically

Comment: You could add js inline while using the Full HTML filter but ideally you would add this to your theme, you could look at the code per node module too. The html will be in your block which you can edit via the frontend or via a module if you want to make it easily exportable

Comment: Good suggestions, i also tought about doing it by templating or via a custom module. Sincerely i hoped for a more specific answer including some code examples :)